# Exact list of property value types for Google Cloud Datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Google Cloud Datastore supports the following value types for properties according to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#properties_and_value_types): array, boolean, blob, date and time, embedded entity, floating point number, geographical point, integer, key, null, text string.

Yet Google Cloud Console (under `Datastore` | `Entities` | `Edit entity`) offers these value types for properties: string, data and time, integer, floating point number, boolean, key, geopoint, array, embedded entity, key, text.

What is the exact correspondence between those types where they differ? E.g., how does the console handle blobs, or can it not? Perhaps Google App Engine types comprise the wnd list (e.g. string vs. text), whereas "native" Google Cloud Datastore types comprise the 1st one (e.g. text string only)?

Comment: Are you asking about type system documentation in Datastore?

Comment: @QuestionAndAnswer The link in the question identifies this documentation.

Comment: When you put blob vlaue from program code, `Blob` is appeared in select box at console. But I don't know what the difference is between `string` and `text`. I believe that gRPC's docs is the exact list. https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/rpc/google.datastore.v1#google.datastore.v1.Value